# How to change the location where Langchain's C Transformer downloads the hugging face model on AWS sagemaker studio labs

Tags: huggingface-transformers, langchain, huggingface, large-language-model, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I used the command :

```
llm = CTransformers(model="TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file = 'llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin', callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
```

to download a LLM model , but I cant find where the model file has been saved. I'm trying to save the model in the directory of my script.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path you want to save your file to.

You’ve you've specified model_file = 'llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin'.
Build the path and filename to output the file. E.g.

```
import os
from ctransformers import CTransformers, StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

# Get the current script's directory
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Define the model file name
model_file_name = 'llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q2_K.bin'

# Construct the full path to save the model
model_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, model_file_name)

# Download the LLM model and save it to the specified path
llm = CTransformers(model="TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GGML", model_file=model_file_path, callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
```

Comment: This can work, but you still can't set the specific path when the first time downloading from huggingface.